# Can I connect to the secondary DB server for a Multi-AZ RDS database instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Multi-AZ database instance in AWS RDS. I would like to connect to its *secondary* server located in the Secondary Zone for the instance using the MySQL CLI. Is this possible to do? If so, how do I find the correct endpoint to connect to?

I would like to use this access to the secondary server to run nightly analytics queries that I would prefer to avoid hitting the primary database server. It's okay for these queries to see a lag in replicated data from the primary database server. And I already have a database user created that limits those analytics queries to truly be read-only, so I don't need to worry about the analytics process accidentally issuing writes to the secondary database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect to the secondary server in an RDS MySQL Multi-AZ setup. You would have to add a read-replica server in order to do this.

Note that if you switched to Aurora MySQL a read-replica would act as your Multi-AZ failover server as well. There is a good table [here](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/) listing the function of Multi-AZ standby servers and read-replica servers in RDS and Aurora databases.

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thanks! I was hoping to avoid to pay for a separate read-replica, but I might just have to do that anyway.